# My macro does not return desired results from a web query

Tags: vba, excel

This macro uses the name of a LLC in a worksheet and searches a website (using [their API](http://www.sos.wa.gov/corps/SearchAPI.aspx)) for the best matched LLC and returns that company's information, specifically the UBI, back to the worksheet.

Currently my code returns nothing and I am stumped as to why. Here is what I have...

Sub TEST()

```
    Dim w As Worksheet
            Set w = ActiveSheet
    Dim Search As String
            Search = Range("E2")
    Dim url As String
            url = "http://www.sos.wa.gov/corps/search_results.aspx?name_type=contains&name=" & Search & "&format=json"
    Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
            Http.Open "GET", url, False
            Http.Send
    Dim resp As String
            resp = Http.ResponseText
    Dim slines As String
    Dim Values As Variant
            Values = Split(resp, ",")
         For i = 0 To UBound(Values)
             slines = Values(i)
             w.Cells(i + 2, 20) = Replace(Values(1), Chr(34) & Chr(173) & Chr(176) & Chr(135) & Chr(133) & Chr(72), "")
         Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I've read the API and no where does it state that it will return the governing persons table...

Comment: guitarthrower it doesn't say it directly look in the search details portion. In order to access it you need the ubi to create a url for the macro code. I'm trying to find a way to access it I don't know a whole lot about macros I have only been teaching myself for a week know.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for clarifying. I can't get your code to return anything, so I'm guessing here, but it seems you are using the `search_results` string in your code. What happens if you change to the `search_detail` string?

Comment: It returns nothing if I change it to details

Comment: I'm officially out of my depth here. I've tried a number of things, but am unable to get the results you are looking for. This is a fascinating problem, but it has me stumped.

Comment: When you sat _my code returns nothing_ is it the HTTP responce that is nothing, or is it the processing of the return string?  (If you havn't already, add a break and examine the value of `Http.ResponseText`).  Note, I can get a responce from that URL, which suggests it's the processing of the returned string that is your issue

Comment: I can see one flaw in your string processing: you `Split` on `,`, then test for `,` in the results using `InStr(slines, ",")`.  This will never return any results because `Split` has removed all the `,`'s

Comment: Yeah its the process, I watched the values and they are empty. ok thanks ill check that out.

Comment: Ok, post an example of the returned string, and the bits you want to extract from it.

Comment: Thanks there are values now but now I guess there is problem with my w.Cells portion it says "object required".ok i will

Comment: { "results" : { "Total": "1", "result":  [ { "UBI": "602024039", "BusinessName": "THE BEN LOMAND ASSOCIATES LLC" } ] }} i just want the numbers after UBI.

Comment: You may not have `Set` w to anything (at least you haven't in the code posted) That will cause the for mentioned.

Comment: By the way, if you include `@UserName` in comments the user will get notified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the issue is in processing the returned string

Sample string from URL

> { "results" : { "Total": "1", "result": [ { "UBI": "602024039", "BusinessName": "THE BEN LOMAND ASSOCIATES LLC" } ] }}

Expected result

> 602024039

Here's a example of processing this string

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim w As Range
    Dim Search As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim resp As String

    Search = Range("E2")
    url = "http://www.sos.wa.gov/corps/search_results.aspx?name_type=contains&name=" & Search & "&format=json"
    Http.Open "GET", url, False
    Http.Send
    resp = Http.ResponseText

    Set w = ActiveCell
    i = InStr(resp, "{ ""UBI"":")
    Do While i > 0
        resp = Mid$(resp, i)
        i = InStr(8, resp, """")
        j = InStr(i + 1, resp, """")
        w = Mid$(resp, i + 1, j - i - 1)
        i = InStr(2, resp, "{ ""UBI"":")
        Set w = w.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

As mentioned in comments, there are many ways to process the string.  An alternative using `Split` could be

```
    Dim values() As String
    values = Split(resp, "{ ""UBI"": """)
    For i = 1 To UBound(values)
        j = InStr(values(i), """")
        w = Left$(values(i), j - 1)
        Set w = w.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
```

I've assumed result are to be returned to the active sheet, starting at the active cell.  Adjust to suit your needs.

Also assumed the web search can return multiple results

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen so much that works perfectly, but just so I can learn and improve my coding what would you say is my codes problem? is it my structure?

Comment: I'd say the issue in your code is the analysis of the string structure.  When breaking a string down into components, you need to determine the features of the string you can use to locate the components you want to extract.  There will always be many ways to attack such a problem.  See update for an alternative method using split